# Query Issue - Postgres /pgadmin4

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

My query is taking hours to run, its over 9M rows in Postgres 9.3 in PgAdmin 4. The data is all string due to the format it came in, i had to use a subquery to break it into columns. So in order to craete the aggregated views i cast each of the elements i need. Because there are millions of rows, there are data elements that have nulls at some point in the table, so i needed the where statement. I have indecies for each of the items in the where clause. All basic btree indexes. Example: Create index loan_age_idx on "gnma2" using btree ("Loan_Age"). The where statement though which is required due to the cast functions are resulting in zero rows returned. What can i do to remove the wheres but keep the cast statement?

```
    create table "t1" as    
Select  
gnma2."Issuer_ID",  
gnma2."As_of_Date",     
gnma2."Agency",     
gnma2."Loan_Purpose",   
gnma2."State",  
gnma2."Months_Delinquent",  
count(gnma2."Disclosure_Sequence_Number") as "Total_Loan_Count",    
avg(cast(gnma2."Loan_Interest_Rate" as double precision))/1000 as "avg_int_rate",   
avg(cast(gnma2."Original_Principal_Balance" as real))/100 as "avg_OUPB",    
avg(cast(gnma2."Unpaid_Principal_Balance" as real))/100 as "avg_UPB",   
avg(cast(gnma2."Loan_Age" as real)) as "avg_loan_age",  
avg(cast(gnma2."Loan_To_Value" as real))/100 as "avg_LTV",  
avg(cast(gnma2."Total_Debt_Expense_Ratio_Percent" as real))/100 as "avg_DTI",   
avg(cast(gnma2."Credit_Score" as real)) as "avg_credit_score",  
left(gnma2."First_Payment_Date",4) as "Origination_Yr"  
    From public."gnma2" 
    where 
    "Loan_Age" >= '1' and 
    "Loan_To_Value" >= '0' and 
    "Total_Debt_Expense_Ratio_Percent" >= '0' and 
    "Credit_Score" >= '0' and 
    "Loan_Interest_Rate" >= '0' and 
    "Original_Principal_Balance" >= '1' and 
    "Unpaid_Principal_Balance" >= '0'
Group By    
gnma2."Issuer_ID",  
gnma2."Agency",     
gnma2."Loan_Purpose",   
gnma2."State",  
gnma2."As_of_Date",     
gnma2."Months_Delinquent",  
gnma2."First_Payment_Date"; 

                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                                   

  HashAggregate  (cost=3496556.07..3496556.65 rows=13 width=91) (actual 
 time=124214.207..124214.207 rows=0 loops=1)
                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on gnma2  
 (cost=166750.75..3496546.65 rows=130 width=91) (actual time=124214.202..124214.20
2 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                                        Recheck Cond: ("Loan_Age" >= '1'::bpchar)
                                                                                        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 4785233
                                                                                        Filter: (("Loan_To_Value" >= '0'::bpchar) AND ("Total_Debt_Expense_Ratio_Percent" >= '0'::bpchar) AND ("Cr
edit_Score" >= '0'::bpchar) AND ("Loan_Interest_Rate" >= '0'::bpchar) AND ("Original_Principal_Balance" >= '1'::bpc
har) AND ("Unpaid_Principal_Balance" >= '0'::bpchar))
                                                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 9311198
                                                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on loan_age_indx  (cost=0.00..166750.72 rows=9029087 width=0) (actual time=5015.865.
.5015.865 rows=9311198 loops=1)
                                                                                                                                                    Index Cond: ("Loan_Age" >= '1'::bpchar)
        Total runtime: 124214.524 ms
```

Comment: where is the `from clause` and `where clause`? what data types are the columns used in the `group by clause`? in particular what is the datatype of "`first_payment_date`"

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** as [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). You should also show us the table definitions and indexes as `create table` or `create index` statements. [edit] your question do **not** post code in comments.

Comment: 9 million rows: try the same query with `psql` instead of pgAdmin. pgAdmin is known to be slow when displaying large result sets.